# Selenium webdriver: Data Driven Framework using JDBC/ADODB

Tags: jdbc, selenium

I am using selenium webdriver to automate websites.How can I extract data from Oracle database using JDBC connection in a hashtable and use it in a data driven framework to pass on parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JDBC/ADODB has nothing to do with Webdriver. Google for JDBC tutorial and you will get enough material on how to connect to a DB, get data and use that data. Some database drivers provide option to get retrieve data from tables into arrays. If you want to get data into hashtable, you will have to create your own logic and then use in your selenium tests.